# C++ A* Algorithm finding struct instance with member value that is lowest in <deque> openlist

Tags: c++, algorithm, syntax, iterator, deque

you will have to forgive me, my grammatical skills are not great.
I am currently trying to create an AStar algoirthm using a unique_ptr  method, and to match the pseudo-code of this I need to be able to find an object in my openlist with the lowest f_cost but I cannot figure out the syntax.

What you need to know about the grid 
its a 10x10 grid, with an array of models that is also 10x10 linked to the struct.

the struct consists of certain booleans not supplied here so I can calculate the f_cost which is the heuristic cost + the manhattan distance

```
struct node
{
//Code by RRNewell Uclan 20618255 -- I have to put this here because my 
//university uses refworks, so this is to confirm on submission it is my work. 

 public:
 int Loc_X;
 int Loc_y;

 int manhattandistance; 
 int f_cost

};

void AStarFindPath(IModel* NodeCubeModels[10][10], node NodeArray[10][10], int storeStartLoc_X, int storeStartLoc_y, int storedestLoc_x, int storedestLoc_y)
{
    deque <unique_ptr < node > > openList; 
    deque <unique_ptr < node > > closeList;  
    deque <unique_ptr <node> >::iterator p;

    unique_ptr <node> currentNode(new node); 
    unique_ptr <node> tmpNode(new node); 



    findstartnode(ANodeCubeModels, SNodeArray); 
    tmpNode->Loc_X = storeStartLoc_X; 
    tmpNode->Loc_y = storeStartLoc_y; 
    cout << "Pushing start node onto list, Node:" << storeLoc_X << ":" << storeLoc_y << endl;

    openList.push_back(move(tmpNode));


    while (currentNode->Loc_X != storedestLoc_x && currentNode->Loc_y != storedestLoc_y)
    {
        deque<node>min_element(openList.begin(), openList.end());<<--- <<HERE>>
        // Is where I want to find node on the open list with the lowest f_cost
    }
}
```

**`<<Here>>`** (Which is labelled on the code to mark `deque<node>min_element(openList.begin(), openList.end());`) is where I want to find the node on the open list with the lowest f_cost.

Does anybody please know the syntactical operation for this ? or if its possible, or do I have to go about it another way ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT
[Pseudocode Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ovj.png)

I am trying to follow this pseudo code, on the highlighted step 5/line 5, by sebastian lague

Reason for edit: A bit more clarification.

Comment: FYI: regarding your comment about the code being your work. Content (and code) posted to StackOverflow falls under the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Comment: That is fine, I changed variable names and ectera, it is just to show that the work originated from myself, and I didn't just copy from other, university code submissions allow concessions on such. This means I will have to reference myself, but thats not a problem.

Comment: You wish to "find the node". But there is a `unique_ptr` that has sole ownership of that node. What do you wish to obtain? A copy of that node? A pointer to that `unique_ptr`?

Comment: I want to find the node with the lowest F_value, then using for example currentNode = Transfer( move( currentNode ) ); transfer ownership of the node with the lowest f_value onto the closed list.  ( an easier explanation is the highlighted section of this pseudo-code i am trying to follow   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ovj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min_element` is a method in the `std` namespace. So:

```
deque <unique_ptr <node> >::iterator current_it = 
                                        std::min_element(openList.begin(), openList.end());
std::unique_ptr<node> current = std::move(*current_it);
```

Note that your `node` structure should either implement an `operator<` or you should provide a comparator. The latter is probably cleaner because the comparison is specific to the algorithm:

```
auto current_it = 
    std::min_element(openList.begin(), openList.end(), 
        [&](const std::unique_ptr < node > & lhs, const std::unique_ptr < node > & rhs) 
        {
            return lhs->f_cost < rhs->f_cost; 
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that has helped a lot.